# How to unlimit the size of view (retain the size of wrap_content) from parent view?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have some colored area which has their own ratios of width and height for responsive layout. I want to paste a view, for example, TextView in the red area as follow:

[image]

Which the TextView retains its own original size instead of limited by the red area.

I tried:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<View
    android:background="#FFFF77"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.01">
    <View
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:background="#77FFFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.01">
        <TextView
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="abcde"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:background="#77FFFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:background="#FFFF77"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

which already set android:clipChildren="false" for the middle element, but the size of TextView seems still limited by the red box:

[image]

how can I make the TextView unlimit the size so that it looks as if sticking on the red area?

Note:in practice, except red area, other area would become transparent, so don't worry about the yellow and cyan area would block the TextView

Answer (score 0):

Try this Library [Spring Layout](https://github.com/sulewicz/springlayout)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something that looks very similar to your screenshot by using `ConstraintLayout`, and as an added benefit, there are only three views inside the parent: one for the vertical line, one for the red box, and one for the text.

There are two concepts at work here:

You can "center" views that are smaller than other views by constraining their edges to each other. So even though the vertical line is much smaller than the parent, when I constrain its left to match the parent's left and its right to match the parent's right, it will draw itself in the (horizontal) center of the parent.

You can then adjust exactly how this "centering" works by setting a `bias` in that direction. Since you previously had a weight of 0.2 on the left and 0.1 on the right, I set the line's *horizontal bias* to 0.67, so it's two-thirds of the way to the right edge of the parent.

I then constrain the left and right of the red view to the left and right of the vertical line, and use the same centering + bias trick to push it two thirds of the way down the screen.

Finally, I constrain all four edges of the text view to match all four edges of the red box. This draws the text view outside of the red box, but centered directly on it.

You can play around with the numbers to get exactly what you want.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFF77">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/verticalLine"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#77FFFF"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.67"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/redSquare"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/verticalLine"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/verticalLine"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.67"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="abcde"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/redSquare"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/redSquare"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/redSquare"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/redSquare"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]